# Intercepting getClass.getResourceAsStream("") with a Java Agent

Tags: java, jvm, javaagents

We have a third party jar that needs patching. I'd figure we'd use a Java Agent to intercept and patch things.

There's two things we need to intercept, a class load, and a json file thats in a jar file.

What's interesting is that calls to `getClass.getResourceAsStream("")` don't seem to be going through our transformer. I guess that makes sense since it's a `ClassFileTransformer`.

So how would we intercept that call? Is there a way to instrument all classloaders?

Comment: Why don't instrument the classes that do the call?

Comment: Where is the transformer source code? How do you attach the agent (`-javaagent:` or hot attachment during runtime)? What do you mean by "calls not going through transformer"? A class file transformer is not an interceptor, it is just a transformer. There are other open questions on my mind, which is why some code (ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) would be really helpful. Your question is way too imprecise in order to attract more than speculative answers, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that's actually a good idea